# $\sup(A+B) = \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

This question has been asked before but if someone could check my proof - it appears different then other answers I have read - I would appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Suppose $A+B = \lbrace a + b : a \in A, b\in B \rbrace$.  And suppose $\sup(A), \sup(B)$ exist.  Prove $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A) + \sup(B)$.

To keep things brief suppose I have already shown that $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A+B$. Now suppose $\exists$ an upper bound $y$ of $A+B$ such that $y < \sup(A) + \sup(B)$.  Hence $y - \sup(A) < \sup(B) \implies\exists b \in B$ such that $y - \sup(A) < b \leq \sup(B) \implies y - b < \sup(A) \implies\exists a \in A$ such that $y - b < a \leq \sup(A) \implies y < a+b \in A+B \implies y$ is not an upper bound of $A+B$. Hence $\sup(A)+\sup(B) = \sup(A+B)$.

Comment: Correct. A stylistic variant, if $y<\sup(A)+\sup(B)$, would be to let $y'=\sup (A)-r$ and $y''=\sup(B)-r$ where $r=(\sup(A)+\sup(B)-y)/2.$ Then $\exists a\in A\,\exists b\in B\,(y'<a\land y''<b).$ But then $y=y'+y''<a+b.$

Comment: Thank you for reviewing and your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your proof is fine, this is one of the instances where a proof by contradiction I think is more confusing than the more direct proof. In particular, a direct proof here would say that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $a > \sup(A) - \epsilon/2$ and $b > \sup(B) - \epsilon/2$. Then, there is an element in $A + B$ that is arbitrarily close to $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$, which shows that $\sup(A + B) \geq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing - yeah the direct proof looks a lot more elegant

Comment: Hi @E-A why for any $\epsilon>0$, there must exists an $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $a>sup(A)- \epsilon /2$ and $b>sup(B)-\epsilon/2$? Suppose $A=\{7\}$ and $B=\{6\}$, in this case $\epsilon$ cannot be any, but must be greater than $1$. Can you help with that?

Comment: @baudo2048 If $A = \{7\} $ and $B = \{ 6\},\ $ then $\sup A = 7$ and $\sup B = 6.\quad \epsilon>0$ can be anything. Whatever $\epsilon$ is, there exists $a\in A$ such that $a > \sup A -\epsilon/2.\ $ In fact, we can always take $a=7$ for any $\epsilon.$ Similarly,  whatever $\epsilon$ is, there exists $b\in B$ such that $b > \sup B -\epsilon/2.\ $ In fact, we can always take $b=6$ for any $\epsilon.$

Comment: Hi @AdamRubinson now it's clear why there exists such $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. If $sup A - \epsilon$ is not the sup, and not even an upper bound hence such $a$ exists by definition of $sup$

Comment: @baudo2048 that sounds about right, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof looks good. As far as presentation goes, I would probably add the following line at the end:

> $y < a + b \implies y$ is not an upper bound of $A+B$. This is a contradiction. Hence for all $y$, if $y$ is an upper bound of $A+B$, we must have $\sup A + \sup B \le y$. It follows that $\sup A + \sup B = \sup(A+B)$.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing and your comments